# FirefoxOS Marketplace - Invalid Archive

Tags: marketplace, firefox-os

Trying to push an application to the Firefox OS Marketplace and getting the detailed error "Invalid Archive"?

The App Validator works fine and reports no errors.
I have pushed other apps zipped up in the same way (using WinRAR) with no issue.
There are no archives included inside the archive and the same archive has been used other places eg: PhoneGap Build with no issue.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Marketplace does some sanity testing on the zip file before working with it. You can see what the code does here: https://github.com/mozilla/zamboni/blob/master/apps/files/utils.py#L322-L331

If a file in the archive is either '..' or starts with a '/' it assumes it is invalid. Also, if a single file within the archive exceeds the limit set by the Marketplace (100MB) it also assumes it is invalid.

Do any of those qualify for your application?

Comment: Nope. Zip file created on Windows - so those filenames are not valid on windows. The whole folder unzipped is only 5 meg.

Comment: If you jump into the #marketplace channel on Mozilla's IRC we could probably help out.

Comment: We discovered a file with '..' in the name that was breaking this archive. I've also updated the code and feedback to include the filename that triggers the "Invalid Archive" message.